# React/Redux: Encapsulate mapStateToProps prop into a variable in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React component that calls a Redux selector function multiple times. I'm looking to refactor by storing the function call within a variable and using that within my component. This is to avoid having to call the same function multiple times when rendering a component versus just one time by storing it into a variable.

In my code, I am using `dataLayerName` to store my selector function: `getDataLayerName`. I notice that the value of `dataLayerName` is logging the function call, and not the actual value from the store.

```
// Code edited for brevity
const COOKIE = 'cookie';

const dataLayerName = ({ getDataLayerName }) => getDataLayerName;

const HowItWorksItem = ({
    getTranslations,
    getDataLayerName,
}) =>
        <div>
            <div>
                {getTranslations({
                    title: 'Title 1',
                    cookie: COOKIE,
                    dataLayerName,
                })}
            </div>
            <div>
                {getTranslations({
                    title: 'Title 2',
                    cookie: COOKIE,
                    dataLayerName,
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    </Cell>;

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    getDataLayerName: selectDataLayerName(state, COOKIE),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HowItWorksItem);
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to include the relevant parts from the original code, I find the example somewhat misleading.

Comment: >I notice that the value of dataLayerName is logging the function call, and not the actual value from the store. 
That's because you didn't wrap `dataLayerName` function in `connect` how would it get the `getDataLayerName` function or redux store state as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

For the work that you are doing, I would recommend two files - one for selecting the data your component will need and one for rendering DOM elements based on your data. I think this will greatly clarify your code.

Also, there are some issues with the code you posted. First, your selectors should be a function of the state. Assuming `getDataLayerName` is a valid selector defined somewhere else, you should be able to use it in your container (the file where you get the data) like so:

HowItWorksItemContainer.js

```
import HowItWorksItem from './HowItWorksItem.js'
import { getDataLayerName } from './selectors.js'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const dataLayerName = getDataLayerName(state);
  return { dataLayerName };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HowItWorksItem);
```

As a side note, I personally think Redux selectors should have a standard suffix, for example I would call it `dataLayerNameSelector` instead of `getDataLayerName`. But it's completely up to you.

Next, you want to render your `HowItWorksItem(s)` to the DOM. I am assuming you want to render just one `HowItWorksItem` with two titles (as in the code you posted). If you want two `HowItWorksItems`, you would create two `HowItWorksItemContainers` in a parent component, like so: `<HowItWorksItemContainer title='Title 1' />`.

There is also an issue with your DOM: there is a closing `</Cell>` tag but no opening tag. For now I just omitted it, but you could also just add an opening `<Cell>` instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import getTranslations from './utilities';

const COOKIE = 'cookie';

function HowItWorksItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            {getTranslations({
                title: 'Title 1',
                cookie: COOKIE,
                props.dataLayerName,
            })}
        </div>
        <div>
            {getTranslations({
                title: 'Title 2',
                cookie: COOKIE,
                props.dataLayerName,
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hopefully this answer gives you some clarity about using Redux selectors to pass data to your components.